# IIS 8.5 .NET Framework 4, application fails to load with Catastrophic Error

Tags: iis

Recently our Application was uplifted from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0. It's based on IIS web Server.

We install our application through wix toolset using an .MSI file.

Application installers creates new customised AppPool and also provide an option to Key in AppPool Userid and Password during installation and this turns out to be the application  pool credentials.
Apppool id can be local id or an domain id

When its on .NET 2.0 its all launching and working fine with both local & domain accounts.

With .Net 4.0 version with local id, it works fine, but with domain id it errors out as below:

Could_not_load_file_or_assembly file:///"Application path\ XXXX.dll'_or_one_of_its_dependencies._Catastrophic_failure_(Exception_from_HRESULT:*0x8000FFFF*(E_UNEXPECTED)) 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko http://localhost/ 500 0 0 0

Mitigation steps we have found out till now is

1) Add physical path credentials to the website which should be same as Application pool username/pwd. And this should launch the website
OR
2) At IIS/Website level change the anonymous authentication to application pool identity instead of IUSR. And this launches the website

Can anyone help me understand why this is the case after .NET 4.0 upgradation

Comment: Most people only experience the well known issues, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes What you observed can be application specific, which if you don't reveal more (a reproducible sample) no one can really help.

Comment: Thanks for Responding.Let me summarize the issue.we have two version of our software. Working software has following configuration : 1) .net 2.0, 2) Apppool with domain id (we key-in during install) 3) Apppool is in Integrated pipeline mode. Not working configuration 1) .Net 4.0, 2) Apppool with domain id (we key-in during install)  3) Apppool is in Classic mode. For software which is not working when we change the anonymous authentication to Application pool identity instead of default IUSR it works fine. whereas .net2.0 version works fine without any edit.